# awk: enumerate fields based on another common field

Tags: arrays, awk

This is most likely done with arrays but I don't know how to build the logic.

Input:

```
uid1 ip1 tag1
uid1 ip1 tag2
uid2 ip2 tag3
uid2 ip2 tag4
uid2 ip2 tag5
```

Desired output:

```
uid1 ip1 tag1,tag2
uid2 ip2 tag3,tag4,tag5
```

I am thinking that maybe this can be achieved by storing all elements in `array1`, then `uid` + `ip` fields in `array2`, then search `array1` by iterating elements from `array2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS=, '{
         k=$1 SUBSEP $2; 
         arr[k] = k in arr ? arr[k] OFS $3 : $0;
      }
      END{
         for(i in arr)
            print arr[i]
      }' infile
```

***Test Results:***

```
$ cat f1
uid1 ip1 tag1
uid1 ip1 tag2
uid2 ip2 tag3
uid2 ip2 tag4
uid2 ip2 tag5

$ awk -v OFS=, '{k=$1 SUBSEP $2; arr[k] = k in arr ? arr[k] OFS $3 : $0;}END{for(i in arr)print arr[i]}' f1
uid1 ip1 tag1,tag2
uid2 ip2 tag3,tag4,tag5
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk -v OFS=, '{                                   # output field separator
         # variable k contains field1 value 
         # and  SUBSEP - Multi-dimensional array separator 
         # and column 2 value

         k=$1 SUBSEP $2; 

         # arr -> array
         # if array key that is variable k already exists in array arr
         # then arr[k] will be existing content of arr[k]  plus
         # field separator (comma) and then field 3 contents
         # else entire row/record which is when array does not have index already

         arr[k] = k in arr ? arr[k] OFS $3 : $0;

      }
      END{                      # END block

         # iterate through array arr
         # and print array value

         for(i in arr)
            print arr[i]

      }' infile
```

***Ternary operator in below***

```
arr[k] = k in arr ? arr[k] OFS $3 : $0;
```

***Is same as***

```
if(k in arr){
  arr[k] = arr[k] OFS $3
}else{
  arr[k] = $0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked as intended. I can't say I can decipher the whole code so I can better understand how it works. Specifically, these parts: `k=$1 SUBSEP $2` and `arr[k] = k in arr ? arr[k] OFS $3 : $0`

Comment: @one-liner added explanation

Comment: @Akshay, Thanks for sharing nice answer cheers.

Comment: Really very well explained

Answer (score 3):

With [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```sh
$ datamash -W -t' ' -g1,2 collapse 3 <ip.txt
uid1 ip1 tag1,tag2
uid2 ip2 tag3,tag4,tag5
```

- `-W` to use space/tab as input field delimiter
- `-t' '` space as output field delimiter
- `-g1,2` group based on fields `1` and `2`
- `collapse 3` operation to be performed on field `3`

Comment: I didn't know about `datamash`, the syntax looks much simpler and cleaner, unfortunately it is not installed by default on my target environment. Will keep this in mind though, for future use.